# Why doesn't gnu prolog support the "false" predicate? (I've changed to swi)

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog, iso-prolog

I've been using the gprolog thingy to do some things in prolog. But now when testing some more code I discovered that it does not support "false". Which is supported by swi?

Answer (score 8):

Use `fail` instead of `false`. I believe the former is in the ISO standard for Prolog. Otherwise, define it yourself:

```
false :- 0=1.
```

or

```
fail :- 0=1.
```

Comment: Wouldn't `false :- fail.` be a clearer definition, since you somehow imply that they have the same effect and/or are synonyms?

Comment: What I meant was: if neither is available, this is how implement one of them. Changed my answer.

Comment: In the meantime, ISO Prolog now has both `fail` and `false`. It is available in GNU and many other systems.

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of GNU Prolog (1.4.0) do support `false/0`.

`false/0` is not defined in the original ISO standard of 1995, but is [part of Cor.2:2012](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#false).